# How to call multiple grunt.run.task within one grunt.registerTask?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, elasticsearch, gruntjs, nodemon

#### What I tried to accomplish, when I type grunt into my cmd shell, is the following:

- start mongod
- start elasticsearch
- start nodemon
- when mongod and elasticsearch runs, execute load_JSON_into_elasticSearch.js (because I need       a connection to both of them)
- when everything is done, open `http://localhost:8080` in the system default browser

The only thing what works at the moment is, that it'll start mongod, elasticsearch and nodemon. That's it...

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
        mongo: {
            command: 'mongod',
            options: {
                async: true
            }
        },
        elasticsearch: {
            command: 'elasticsearch',
            options: {
                async: true
            }
        }
    },
    nodemon: {
        dev: {
            script: 'server.js'
        }
    },
    execute: {
        target: {
            src: ['load_JSON_into_elasticSearch.js']
        }
    },
    open: {
        dev: {
            path: 'http://localhost:8080',
            app: 'Google Chrome'
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell-spawn');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-execute');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');

grunt.registerTask('startServices', ['shell', 'nodemon']);
grunt.registerTask('indexAndBrowser', ['execute', 'open']);

grunt.registerTask('default', 'Start it...', function() {

    var done = this.async();

    grunt.log.writeln('\n===========================================\nStarting Mongod/ ElasticSearch/ Nodemon...\n===========================================\n');

    var init = function () {
        grunt.task.run('startServices');

        var process = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                grunt.log.writeln('\n==================================\nStarting Index and Browser...\n==================================\n');
                grunt.task.run('execute');
            }, 20000);
        };

        process();
        done();
    };

    init();

});

};
```

Comment: 5 hours really isn't very long - tag subscribers won't have been emailed yet even. Two tips: the first paragraph of your question is shown in summary listings, make it "hook" readers with an interesting intro. Make sure your question is as easy as possible for someone to dig in and start fiddling. This isn't the area I'm an expert in, but the questions I'm most likely to answer are interesting, easy to repro ones. Also you don't usually need to write "edit" or "update" when editing - the info is all there in the changelog.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would recommend using grunt-run (I wrote it to manage similar needs).

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-run

It has a few useful features that you could take advantage of. Here is an example of what using grunt-run might look like for you:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  run: {
    elasticsearch: {
      cmd: 'elasticsearch',
      options: {
        wait: false,
        ready: /started/
      }
    },
    mongo: {
      command: 'mongod',
      options: {
        wait: false,
        ready: /waiting for connections on port/
      }
    },
    load_json_into_es: {
      args: [
        'load_JSON_into_elasticSearch.js'
      ]
    }
  },
  open: {
    dev: {
      path: 'http://localhost:8080',
      app: 'Google Chrome'
    }
  },
  nodemon: {
    dev: {
      script: 'server.js'
    }
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');

grunt.registerTask('default', [
  'run:mongo'
  'run:elasticsearch'
  'run:load_json_into_es',
  'nodemon',
  'open'

]);
```